# LED s calculation of beam area, dosage and energy from data sheet information

Tags: led

I have an application with LEDs with following data sheet

- [LED631E](http://www.hasunopto.com/sale-9629137-led525l-led528ehp-led555l-led570l-led590l-led591e-led600l-led610l-led625l-single-color-visible-leds-.html)    635 nm
- optical power 4 mW
- half angle    20°
- FWHMa   10 nm,

Could you help me with calculation of beam area at the distance of 20 mm from LED?

Also please help me with calculation of dosage (J/cm<sup>2</sup>) and total energy delivered [Joules] in 20 minutes at the same distance : 20 mm from LED.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why are you choose RED LEDs for dosage? instead of UV? or IR?

Comment: I want to make a project like below https://manualzz.com/doc/7171031/adilight-2-user-manual

Comment: Fascinating .  Has the Company: ACN:ADILYFE PTY LTD
144 890 059 filed for bankrupcy?

Notice

ASIC has received an application to deregister the Company under s601AA. 13 March 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only care about the energy within the half angle (angle at which the magnitude is 50%), here is what I come up with. Without a curve of brightness vs angle the amount within the half angle can't be determined. I made a wild guess. With the curve, you will need to integrate in polar coordinates, something I might have been able to do 40 years ago, no chance now without many hours of research.

I am guessing that you will need multiple IR LEDs for your application, to calculate the optical power with overlapping curves will probably be necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it is about 10 LEDs placed in line .  I have another manufacturer with the same type of LED and the characteristics are in the link below :   https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/73009f3b97c41818-C3B42E87-D6AF-AA10-E84439B88C4FCAD7/LED631E-SpecSheet.pdf

Comment: Yes. You are right, i  have an application with 10 LED s with red colour 635nm for obtaining an uniform lighting of a rectangle surface of 30mm x 100 mm.  The distance 15 or 20 mm is for finding of calculation formulas. I need red for special application of Photoactivation device used for activate with red, green and yellow., link for what I want to do : https://manualzz.com/doc/7171031/adilight-2-user-manual

Comment: I want to build for me an Photoactivation device, that produces red, green and yellow colour for photoactivation of stem cell and PRP.  The patent for above model is in the link : https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c2/5b/0b/ea71b328591a4a/US9752138.pdf

Comment: Another problem is with placing of LEDs near the cylinder : How would be better : in line or on the both side (placed 180 degree) of cylinder to obtain uniform activation of the content of cylinder with diameter of 30 mm and length of 100 mm . An important fact - the solution has a degree of transparency , so it is possible to apply 10 LEDs with red colour on the single side of cylinder. Thanks for your opinion. Above information in the 2 links are the most information found in the last 6 months on websites.

Comment: You may want to specify the tolerance on radiated Max:Min which is necessary but impossible with the LED specs given as the overlap will create a wide variation in dosage. unless you use a diffuser.

Comment: As far as healing properties, my experience has been always positive using 5~25um or sometimes called FIR ( far IR) by the Japanese and mineral therapy by the Chinese using phosphors minerals found in some clays such as Germanium, Silicon etc and others to convert heat ( short IR) to long IR. No side effects and always promotes self-healing. ( except eyes must be protected from catarogenic response)  I bought one of the 1st devices at a trade show in SFO in mid 80's which is now standard equipment for all Dr's of acupuncture

Comment: for LED illumination you need a better design for smooth intensity and not just 5mm LEDs every 25mm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92165/discussion-between-costas-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).